# How to make StreamBuilder not rebuild all widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am currently working on a chat application, when I added a record everything is fine but when play record or any audio and send message audio is stop and make initState again

this is streambuilder:

```
    class MessageStreamBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController messageScrollController;
  const MessageStreamBuilder({Key? key, required this.messageScrollController}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MessageStreamBuilder> createState() => _MessageStreamBuilderState();
}

class _MessageStreamBuilderState extends State<MessageStreamBuilder> {
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> _stream;
  late ChatCubit cubit;
  final int _limit = 100;
  final int _limitIncrement = 20;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //_messageScrollController.animateTo(0, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    super.initState();
    _stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('GeneralChat')
        .orderBy('time', descending: true)
        .limit(_limit)
        .snapshots();
    cubit = ChatCubit.get(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>> message = snapshot.data!.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
              controller: widget.messageScrollController,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (element, index) {
                return Message(
                    messages: message, messageIndex: index);
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: SpinKitWave(
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

and this is audio widget:

```
    class _AudioMessageState extends State<AudioMessage> {
  final AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();
  final url = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _init();
  }
  Future<void> _init() async {
    try {
      await _player.setUrl(widget.audioUrl[0]);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('An error occured $e');
    }
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        playButtonAudio(_player),
        const SizedBox(width: 10,),
        Expanded(
            child: progressBarAudio(_player)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

i need to make audio play when send message dont stop Is there another way instead of StreamBuilder....

iam using firebase
and no setState() use cubit

Comment: did u solve this?